# I accidentally synced in Gmail account to work computer

Tags: google-chrome

I accidentally synced my gmail account to my work Google Chrome browser. As a result, all my bookmarks showed up in the google browser.

I deleted all of the bookmarks. Then I deleted my gmail account from Settings/People.

Is there anything else I have to do to make sure all of my personal gmail information is off the google chrome account? Should I have an administrator do an uninstall?

Thanks

Comment: Just delete the Chrome user profile directory.

Comment: And where can I find that in a Windows 8 computer? Thanks.